# Translation of XHTML page with MathML

Tags: unicode, xhtml, internationalization, automation, mathml

We have few XHTML pages with MathML in them. All are generated using Amaya. We have a requirement to translate them to different languages, but Amaya doesn't seem to support Unicode text encoding. Right now we plan to replace the text in XHTML manually.

I would be happy to know of other possible ways of implementing this translation process. Translation should maintain structure of the MathML.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML to create a [translation dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086231/how-to-do-i18n-with-xsl-and-xml) with [Math entities](http://graphemica.com/). The translation can be done programmatically using [XSLT](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4876.html) and [Amaya](https://github.com/w3c/Amaya-Editor) or [E4X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280911/proper-way-to-replace-text-in-e4x-element) and AS3.